# understand how a commit is reachable

Tags: git, git-reflog, git-fsck

I deleted a branch and I was presuming that a certain commit (let's call it `C`) was no longer reachable. I was able to find the commit in question using `git reflog`. However, I am puzzled by the fact that that commit doesn't show up when I do:

```
git fsck --unreachable --no-reflogs
```

I was expecting that `C` was unrechable, and yet it doesn't show up in the output of the above command.

So, the question is:
Given a commit `C`, is there a way to understand how C is reached?
`git describe` does the opposite, in a sense, of what I am trying to achieve. When I do `git describe C` I get the tag that is reachable from `C` whereas I want to opposite. I want to understand which tag / branch can be used to reach `C`, and thus understand why `git fsck` does not report it as unreachable.

Comment: Also, do note that "reachable" and "not collected" does not follow the same rules. A commit can be unreachable, but not yet collected, and thus if you have the SHA of the commit, you can still access it.

Comment: Since I am specifically invoking `git fsck --no-reflogs` I understand that the reflog does not affect commit reachability. The commit is not collected as I was able to resurrect it with `checkout -b`. It is also reachable since it fails to show up in `git fsck`. The aim of my question is to understand how its reachable status is determined.

Comment: @IMSoP. Yes and that's the correct answer as it helped me identify another branch that was also used to reach that commit.

Comment: @IMSoP I voted to close it as duplicate but it seems that that's all I can do